# Is it safe to run two instances of `stack` at the same time?

Tags: haskell-stack

See title.

It would be nice if I could run multiple instances of stack at the same time. It would allow for some nice parallelisation.
I do *not* know which commands I want to run beforehand, so I can not just merge the commands and have stack figure out how to do it in parallel.

If this is not possible. Is it in the scope of Stack?

Answer (score 0):

Running multiple instances of stack concurrently is supposed to be possible and safe.

I know that parts of `~/.stack` are protected by file locks – the project state in `my-proj/.stack-work` [should get that in the future](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2958).